# iOS call extension from my app

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

Can I call an app extension (provided from another app) from my app.

Sample Scenario:
I have a photo asset in my app which need to be edited (crop, scale, filter...).

Now I wan't to call an app extension from my app, which supports image editing. The extension starts, the user edit the photo and I get the extension callback with the new image (data or path or something else).

I search around and only the scenarios I found is where someone creates an extension (many tutorials & apple documentations) which can be used in the photos app for example.

Or is it not possible to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hope this helps you: http://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/,   http://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so Inter process communication is not possible in iOS each app is sandboxed